# Cómo reconectar ADO con SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012, ado.net

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web con ASP.NET MVC, C# y ADO.NET para la conexión con la base de datos SQL Server 2012. Este desarrollo lo he realizado en una PC y ahora he copiado el proyecto a otra PC, así mimso la base de datos también la he restaurado en la segunda PC, ya configuré el ODBC de la misma manera que en la PC original, sin embargo al compilar el proyecto me muestra el siguiente error:
 ***Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error al buscar el servidor o instancia especificado)***
 Alguien ha realizado algo similar? Qué configuraciones adicionales debo hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

revisa si el nombre de la instancia de SQL quedo exactamente igual a la que tenias en el otro pc, si esta igual fijate si al momento de crear la conexion no quedo con la direccion IP en vez del nombre de la maquina y la instancia.

Comment: Efectivamente se trataba del nombre de la instancia

Comment: Excelente  te agradezco votes por la respuesta